# Firefox globalmenu for Zotero Standalone

Tags: unity, firefox, xulrunner, zotero

As far as I understand it the source code of Firefox is hacked in order to use the unity global menu.

Zotero Standalone is based on the same architecture as Firefox (xulrunner). Would it be possible to implement the same hack for this piece of software as well? Would be great to improve the consistency of my desktop.

Comment: It should be possible. There's a bug report for that at the zotero standalone bug track [here](https://github.com/zotero/zotero/issues/302). The global menu integration seems to be (de)activated based on the value of the `ui.use_unity_menubar` preference. Someone has to grep for `use_unity_menubar` in the firefox/xulrunner codebase for Ubuntu, and port the functionality to zotero standalone.

Comment: Yeah I tried to look into that, and it turns out, that the patch is way to complicated for my js expertise...

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019, the preferred way of installing Zotero is by using [Emiliano Heyns' packages](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb).

His repository also provides [alternative packages](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb#unofficial-global-menu-support-for-ubuntu-1904) with unofficial Global Menu support for Ubuntu 19.04+.

For additional information about the provided packages, see the [README file](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-deb/blob/master/README.md).